# android MIUI device specific issue

Tags: android

Before down vote, give reason in comment so i will ask better question next time :|

I am facing issue in special mi mobile.

i search for this and get some points.

1. it is device specific issue.
2. enable auto start from setting.
3. *excludeFromRecent* in manifest file.
4. one option is there if i will lock app from recent then did not kill alarm and services, but considering point 3 i can not get app in recent, i fix this for some reason.

please answer me if you have solutions.

when user click on clear button from recent screen (Please look into image)
then whole service and alarm will destroy and not start till i will start app manually.

[image]

i see some UltimateSpecialAppsList in mi phone they added all popular apps and it will working good. so do i need to add my app in this list? if yes then how?

Comment: Security app controls evrything in mi and redmi devices